# Ejabberd give user registration access to only my clients

Tags: ejabberd

I am using ejabberd in my chat server and I am registering new users from android app.But when I give to full access to user registrations other clients can register new users.Example:Pidgin can register new user.How can I block them ? I just want to give access for only my clients.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to modify the registration module to include a shared secret. This is not terribly secure, but it should somehow limit the risk of abuse. Make sure the traffic is also encrypted with TLS in that case, otherwise it will be pointless.